# Frozen bathtub pipes

Tags: plumbing, freezing

We had six inches of snow over the weekend and it was zero degrees this morning. Last night I realized that although I had been running water in the kitchen, the washer and the bathroom sink, the bathtub will not dispense water. It initially spit out a trickle then nothing. I took a bath by heating water on the stove and it drains fine.
The tub backs up to a shed outside the front door where it is covered by a board.  I am in the middle stack of three in a 1973 condo building.
It is going to be about 18 degrees tonight and I am debating calling a plumber if it does not thaw on its own tomorrow. I am trying to watch money.
I can run an extension cord and put a heating dish in the shed which will buzz if it is touched or moved while on or blow a hair dryer provided I can get the board off. I am a single woman.
Can this wait a day or so? We will be in the 60s in two days. Any advice appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If water is not running it can wait. The problem may be that when it thaws the pipe may have ruptured. If the pipe is ruptured and the ice melts it could make a mess in a wall but it may also be a pipe under the house that you may not realize it is leaking unless it is large and your water pressure drops. But with cold temps some times it can take a few days above freezing and closer to 40 to thaw if the floors are insulated. You may get lucky and not have any leaks when it thawes out.

Comment: Answers go down there, @EdBeal. :)

Comment: This is an *outdoors* bathtub?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested: If water is not running it can wait. The problem may be that when it thaws the pipe may have ruptured. If the pipe is ruptured and the ice melts it could make a mess in a wall but it may also be a pipe under the house that you may not realize it is leaking unless it is large and your water pressure drops. But with cold temps some times it can take a few days above freezing and closer to 40 to thaw if the floors are insulated. You may get lucky and not have any leaks when it thawes out.